# Xamarin.Forms Picker problem with static ItemsSource

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin-binding

I have a static collection `Networks`:

```
public class NetworkSettings
{
    private static List<NetworkSetting> _networks;

    public static IList<NetworkSetting> Networks
    {
        get
        {
            if (_networks == null)
            {
                _networks = new List<NetworkSetting>
                {
                    new NetworkSetting(),
                    ...
                    ...
                }
            }
            return _networks;
        }
    }
```

So far so good. This class is initialised, and valid.

When I bind to it from a Picker with:

```
[View]
<xmlns:models="clr-namespace:AppName.Models" />

<Picker ItemsSource="{x:Static models:NetworkSettings.Networks}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNetworkSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I get a NullReference exception (something to do with the ItemsSource).

But if I bind to the ViewModel version of the same data:

```
[ViewModel]
public IList<NetworkSetting> NetworkSettings => Models.NetworkSettings.Networks;

[View]
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkSettings}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNetworkSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

..then everything is fine.
What's the difference? Why does it accept the static binding?

Comment: I found that when you change `IList<NetworkSetting> Networks` to `List<NetworkSetting> Networks` ,it works.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Add that as an answer, and I'll accept. I was following the guidelines on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.picker.itemssource?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Picker_ItemsSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
  public static IList<NetworkSetting> Networks
```

to

```
   public static List<NetworkSetting> Networks
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Static binding is a little different and will need to use the `x:Static` *markup extension*

[Bindings and Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#bindings-and-collections)

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{x:Static local:NetworkSettings.Networks}" />
```

Where local is defined

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:blahblahblah;assembly=blahblahblah"
```

Comment: APart from the name of the namespace, that's exactly what I have done. I will amend the question.